# need some help to resolve this loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, math

I need help with this problem.
I must use a function that simulates the launch of two dice and returns an array with the result (example [3,2]). To simulate the launch I must use the function math.random and get values between 1 and 6.
 I must add the result of throwing the dice and save the result of the sum in an array "launch result"... then I must do 36,000 pitches and calculate which was the most repeated result.
I have managed to generate the array with the sum of the values of the launch, but from the loop of 36000 launches I can only generate individual array and not one set.  It would be from the loop that does not meet the requirements.

```
function launchTwoDice() {
    let dice1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1) + 1);
    let dice2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1) + 1);
    let dices = [];
    dices.push(dice1);
    dices.push(dice2);
    let sum = dices.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    });
    let resultOfLaunch = [];
    resultOfLaunch.push(sum);
    return resultOfLaunch;
};

let allLaunches = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 36000; i++) {
    let result = launchTwoDice();
    allLaunches[result] = allLaunches[result] + 1;
    allLaunches.push(result);

};

console.log(allLaunches);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is wrong with the code you show? Do you have a specific question for us? Please read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: hi! thank you.
I have managed to generate the array with the sum of the values of the launch, but from the loop of 36000 launches I can only generate individual array and not one set. it would be from the loop that does not meet the requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the edit to your question. However, you still have not asked us any question. And your "one set" is not clear. Please clarify further and ask a specific question. (I have added the `javascript` tag to your question due to your code and your user name.)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I tried to solve this loop problem and i tested too, it works fine for me, have a look to the code.

```
 function launchTwoDice() {
        let dice1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1) + 1);
        let dice2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1) + 1);
        return dice1+dice2;
    };
    let allLaunches = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 36000; i++) { 
        let result = launchTwoDice(); 
        if(allLaunches[result] == undefined)
         { allLaunches[result] = 1; } 
         else { allLaunches[result] = allLaunches[result] + 1};
    };
```

The main problem was, when we put count in array, `allLaunches[result] = allLaunches[result] + 1` like this, In this case `allLaunches[result]` in undefined and `undefined + 1 = NaN`

So place a condition before adding count in `allLaunches` array.

on `console.log(allLaunches)`

```
(13) [empty × 2, 1041, 2024, 2923, 3982, 5128, 5968, 4980, 4055, 2930, 1929, 1040]
2: 1041
3: 2024
4: 2923
5: 3982
6: 5128
7: 5968
8: 4980
9: 4055
10: 2930
11: 1929
12: 1040
length: 13
__proto__: Array(0)
```